# timeseries forecasting when datapoints doesn't start at same time period

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series

I have a dataset which has lifecycle information of different products but all the products doesn't start selling in same period or same year/quarter.In this case how should i do time series modelling like ARIMA? are there any additional attributes which i have to extract to perform analysis?

Comment: I am facing the same problem with water quality time series which do not start at the same time and sometimes do not have the same frequencies over years. Have you found any answer to your question?

Comment: No i didn't fins answer yet,one approach is to do survival analysis on the data